# Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' dispise of importing `CommonModule/ReactiveFormsModule/FormsModule`

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have created `AddEditComponent` component in a separate module. I have included in the component module all the dependency modules like `CommonModule/FormsModule/ReactiveFormsModule` and when I try to compile it, compiler displays the error `Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'`
The errors disappear only if I add in the parent routing module lazy loading:

```
loadChildren: () => import('./add.edit/add.edit.module').then(m => m.AddEditModule)
```

instead of

```
component: AddEditComponent
```

which I have commented out because if I use the lazy loading my `AddEditComponent` doesn't even come up on the screen(but it compiles).
I have spent hours looking into that and can't solve it. Can someone see what am I missing please?

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="mb-3 row">
...
</form>
```

AddEditModule :

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Constants } from 'src/app/constants';

import { NGX_MAT_DATE_FORMATS, NgxMatDateAdapter, NgxMatDateFormats, NgxMatDatetimePickerModule } from '@angular-material-components/datetime-picker';
import { NGX_MAT_MOMENT_DATE_ADAPTER_OPTIONS, NgxMatMomentAdapter } from '@angular-material-components/moment-adapter';

import { DateAdapter, MAT_DATE_FORMATS, MAT_DATE_LOCALE } from '@angular/material/core';
import { MatDatepickerModule } from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MaterialModule } from 'src/app/material/material.module';

import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AddEditComponent } from './add-edit.component';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { AccountsRoutingModule } from '../accounts-routing.module';
import { MomentDateAdapter } from '@angular/material-moment-adapter';


const CUSTOM_MOMENT_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput:  Constants.dateFormat,
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: Constants.dateFormat,
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
  },
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AddEditComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AccountsRoutingModule,

    MaterialModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatTableModule,
    MatDatepickerModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    NgxMatDatetimePickerModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
   
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: CUSTOM_MOMENT_FORMATS},

  ],
})
export class AddEditModule { }
```

AddEditComponent:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { first } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MustMatch } from 'src/app/_helpers';
import { TimeHandler } from 'src/app/_helpers/time.handler';

import * as moment from 'moment';
import { Account, Role } from 'src/app/_models';
import { UserFunction } from 'src/app/_models/userfunction';
import { AccountService, AlertService } from 'src/app/_services';
import { Constants } from 'src/app/constants';

@Component({ templateUrl: './add-edit.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./add-edit.component.less'], })
export class AddEditComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
...
}
```

The parent routing module that references my `AddEditComponent`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AddEditComponent } from './add.edit/add-edit.component';
import { FunctionComponent } from './function.component';
import { ListComponent } from './list.component';
import { MainSchedulerComponent } from './main-scheduler/main-scheduler.component';
import { AutoGeneratorComponent } from './max-flow-schedules/auto-generator/auto-generator.component';
import { ScheduleAllocatorComponent } from './schedule.allocator.component';
import { UploadAccountsComponent } from './upload-accounts/upload-accounts.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: ListComponent },
    { path: 'add', /* loadChildren: () => import('./add.edit/add.edit.module').then(m => m.AddEditModule) */ component: AddEditComponent },
    { path: 'upload', component: UploadAccountsComponent},
    { path: 'auto-generate-schedules', component: AutoGeneratorComponent},
    { path: 'edit/:id', /* loadChildren: () => import('./add.edit/add.edit.module').then(m => m.AddEditModule) */component: AddEditComponent },
    { path: 'function/:id', component: FunctionComponent },
    { path: 'schedule/:id', component: ScheduleAllocatorComponent },
    { path: 'schedule-generate', component: MainSchedulerComponent},
    
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AccountsRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: AddEditModule should contain RouterModule and route `{path: '', component: AddEditComponent}` to render it at all. If you are using latest angular you could make a component standalone, which can help you get rid of a module and reduce the nessecity to setup additional route. You could have just imported the component inside of a `loadComponent`

Comment: I did as you suggested , make  AddEditComponent standalone . So I added routing `{ path: 'add', loadComponent: () => AddEditComponent },` to `AccountsRoutingModule`. I get same error message

Answer (score 0):

I have spent hours on tracking down the `Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'` to find out that the culprit is a missing import of my module in my component class.
Every time I added import `import { AddEditModule } from './add.edit.module';` Visual Studio Code marked it as unsed so I deleted it not realizing that it is needed for the common definitions  and `form` components. I didn't think that the module to which component belongs is needed in import statement of the component.
I just thought that it is migically included behind the scenes.
What are other people thoughts?

Comment: On the other hand I have never seen component importing explicitly module? Something is not right. Can somebody comment on this please?